# Popups using shiny

Tags: r

I'd like to make a simple popup that prompts users to select files. I've found shiny, but am not sure how to adapt the code. The prompts should be:

1. "Please select data file". The user selects an excel file
2. "Please select settings file". Another excel file.

> ```
> library(shiny)
> ui = fluidPage(
>   actionButton("show", "Show")
> )
> server = function(input, output) {
>   observeEvent(input$show, {
>     showNotification("This is a notification.")
>   })
> }
>
> shinyApp(ui, server)
> ```

Comment: Is [file upload](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) insufficient for your task?

Comment: Thanks. This is going to sound very basic, but I can see the example code on http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#uploads but when I paste into RStudio script it doesn't do anything